# Two lines of text in a UISegmentedControl

Tags: ios, uilabel, uisegmentedcontrol, uiinterfaceorientation

Try as I might, I can't solve a UISegmentedControl bug for an iOS7 iPhone app.

When I create the segmented control, I use this code:

```
NSArray *segmentedControlItemArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"Nominal:\n27 inch", @"Actual:\n700c x 23mm", @"Actual:\n700c x 20mm", nil];
_wheelDiameterSegmentedControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:segmentedControlItemArray];
_wheelDiameterSegmentedControl.frame = CGRectMake(0, 102, 290, 50);
_wheelDiameterSegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 0;
_wheelDiameterSegmentedControl.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.35 green:0.4 blue:0.9 alpha:1.0];

for (id segment in [_wheelDiameterSegmentedControl subviews]) {
    for (id label in [segment subviews]) {
        if ([label isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]]) {
            UILabel *titleLabel = (UILabel *) label;
            titleLabel.numberOfLines = 0;   
        }   
    }  
}

[_wheelDiameterSegmentedControl addTarget:self
                     action:@selector(pickOne:)
           forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

[_wheelDiameterMenuContainer addSubview:_wheelDiameterSegmentedControl];
```

Sadly, I can't post images, or I would show you a picture of exactly the control I want: each of the segments in the UISegmented Control has two lines of text, with a line break exactly where I asked for it.

On rotation, though, I'd like to keep the segmented control full-width, and the line breaks look silly in segments that wide. So, in willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation, I've included the following code, with no line breaks in the strings:

```
    [_wheelDiameterSegmentedControl setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 102, 450, 50)];
    [_wheelDiameterSegmentedControl setTitle:@"Nominal: 27 inch" forSegmentAtIndex:0];
    [_wheelDiameterSegmentedControl setTitle:@"Actual: 700c x 23mm" forSegmentAtIndex:1];
    [_wheelDiameterSegmentedControl setTitle:@"Actual: 700c x 20mm" forSegmentAtIndex:2];
```

And once again, if I could insert an image, I would show you an image of exactly what I want: a wide UISegmented Control with no line breaks in the labels (1 line of text per label).

Here's where I run in to trouble. My choices, when I rotate back to portrait, seem to be:

1 line of label text, truncated, with the format

"Actual: 7..."

when I just reset the size of the UISegmentedControl using

```
[_wheelDiameterSegmentedControl setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 102, 290, 50)];
```

2 lines of label text, truncated, with the format

"Actual:
700c x ..."

when I reset the size and also reset the string values and rerun the loop of code that sets the label's numberOfLines to 2, using

```
    NSArray *segmentedControlItemArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"Nominal:\n27 inch", @"Actual:\n700c x 23mm", @"Actual:\n700c x 20mm", nil];

    [_wheelDiameterSegmentedControl setTitle:[segmentedControlItemArray objectAtIndex:0] forSegmentAtIndex:0];
    [_wheelDiameterSegmentedControl setTitle:[segmentedControlItemArray objectAtIndex:1] forSegmentAtIndex:1];
    [_wheelDiameterSegmentedControl setTitle:[segmentedControlItemArray objectAtIndex:2] forSegmentAtIndex:2];
    for (id segment in [_wheelDiameterSegmentedControl subviews]) {
        for (id label in [segment subviews]) {
            if ([label isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]]) {
                UILabel *titleLabel = (UILabel *) label;
                titleLabel.numberOfLines = 2;
            }
        }
    }
    [_wheelDiameterSegmentedControl setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 102, 290, 50)];
```

3 lines of label text, with the format

"Actual:
700c x
20mm"

which is what I get when I replace the forced numberOfLines = 2 above with the numberOfLines = 0 that worked when I set up the UISegmentedControl in the first place.

What I'd like is what I get when I create the control, which is

"Actual:
700c x 20mm"

But no matter what I've tried (putting the string and numberOfLines code into willRotateToInterfaceOrientation or didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation; re-setting the frame of the UISegmentedControl before changing the text; re-setting the frame after changing the text...), I can't get my nice, neat, two-line label back. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 8):

Aha! Something about how the OS is handling the size of the label when it rotates is different from how it handles the label when it's created. So I forced the size of the frame of the label, using

```
for (id segment in [_wheelDiameterSegmentedControl subviews]) {

    for (id label in [segment subviews]) {

        if ([label isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]]) {

            UILabel *titleLabel = (UILabel *) label;

            //inserting line here, to make the frame behave nicely:
            //
            titleLabel.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 97, 50);
            //
            //continuing as before

            titleLabel.numberOfLines = 0;

        }
    }
}
```

and now it displays exactly as I want/expect. Huzzah!

---

If you're just trying to get two (or more) lines of text in your UISegmentedControl. Using Herzian's amazing technology!  Here's just another code example, that may help people...

```
self.yourSlider .. set the height manually (can't easily do it in XIB)
// now use amazing Herzian technology...
for (id segment in [self.yourSlider subviews])
    for (id label in [segment subviews])
        {
        if ([label isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]])
            {
            UILabel *titleLabel = (UILabel *) label;
            titleLabel .. set the width to say 80, per your layout;
            (the width us typically too low)
            titleLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
            }
        }
```

thank you so much, again.

Comment: It does not work in iOS 7 because, in iOS7 and onward they are using UISegmentLabel instead of UILabel, and UISegmentLabel is somehow protected/private class.

Answer (score 1):

working code in ios 7 :

I have a segment controller with four segments and I need it in 2 lines for text. So I have added `UILabel` as a `subview` in segment of `UISegmentedControl` and it is working good. I have tried all other ways but in ios 7 and ios 8 it is working good right now.

```
for(int k =0;k<4;k++)
    {
        NSString *text = @"title name";
        UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] init];
        label.frame = CGRectMake(10,2, (self.segmentcontroll.frame.size.width/4), 34);
        label.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:12.0];
        label.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        label.text = text;
        label.numberOfLines = 0;
        label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
        [label sizeToFit];
        [[[self.segmentcontroll subviews] objectAtIndex:k] addSubview:label];
}
```

Comment: Nice idea, but [[self.segmentcontroll subviews] objectAtIndex:k] does not always return in order of left to right

Comment: @david72  yes you are right. But we can manage that in either way. By tag or by text or any other condition.

Answer (score 0):

And Herzian's solution as a category if anyone wants it.  Remember to call it in VWA instead of VDL so it happens after autosizing / rotation

```
#import "UISegmentedControl+MultiLine.h"

@implementation UISegmentedControl (MultiLine)

-(void)setupMultiLine
{
  self.frame = CGRectMake(self.frame.origin.x,
                          self.frame.origin.y,
                          self.frame.size.width,
                          self.frame.size.height*1.6);
  for (id segment in self.subviews)
  {
    for (id label in [segment subviews])
    {
      if ([label isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]])
      {
        UILabel *titleLabel = (UILabel*) label;
        titleLabel.frame = CGRectMake(0,
                                      0,
                                      titleLabel.frame.size.width,
                                      titleLabel.frame.size.height*1.6);
        titleLabel.numberOfLines = 0;

      }
    }
  }
}

@end
```