# UISegmentedControl text with multiple lines

Tags: ios, swift, uisegmentedcontrol

Is there any possibility to make UISegmentedControl with multiple lines of text in iOs 9+?

So far i've tryed:

1. Variants from SO topics:
   [This,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19868284/two-lines-of-text-in-a-uisegmentedcontrol) [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5614284/uisegmentedcontrol-text-with-multiple-lines) [and this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28028619/is-it-possible-to-create-multi-line-uisegmentedcontrol)
2. Make an extension:

   ```
   extension UISegmentedControl
   {
       func makeMultiline(numberOfLines: Int)
       {
           for segment in self.subviews
           {
               let labels = segment.subviews.filter { $0 is UILabel }  // [AnyObject]
               labels.map { ($0 as UILabel).numberOfLines = numberOfLines }    
           }
       }
   }
   ```
3. Inherit from UISegmentedControl and set new class to SegmentedControl in Identity Inspector

   ```
   class MultilineSegmentedControl: UISegmentedControl
   {
       override func didMoveToSuperview()
       {
           for segment in subviews
           {
               for subview in segment.subviews
               {
                   if let segmentLabel = subview as? UILabel
                   {
                       segmentLabel.numberOfLines = 2
                   }
               }
           }
       }
   }
   ```
4. Set image with text instead of title and change frame of UISegmentedControl in

   ```
   viewDidLayoutSubviews()
   ```

   method. It makes UISegmentedControl height larger, but image keeps it's height as if UISegmentedControl didn't enlarge and on first interaction UISegmentedControl shrinks to it's default height.

Answer (score 5):

Try out below code, find out all segmentedControl sub `UILabel` and set `numberOfLines`.

```
for segmentViews in segmentedControl.subviews {
    for segmentLabel in segmentViews.subviews {
        if segmentLabel is UILabel {
            (segmentLabel as! UILabel).numberOfLines = 0
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: More compact version: segmentedControl.subviews.compactMap({ $0 as? UILabel }).forEach({ $0.numberOfLines = 0 })

Answer (score 4):

Maybe it's a bit late but here is my subclass to resolve this problem in swift 3 :

```
@IBDesignable class MySegmentedControl: UISegmentedControl {

    @IBInspectable var height: CGFloat = 29 {
        didSet {
            let centerSave = center
            frame = CGRect(x: frame.minX, y: frame.minY, width: frame.width, height: height)
            center = centerSave
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable var multilinesMode: Bool = false

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        for segment in self.subviews {
            for subview in segment.subviews {
                if let segmentLabel = subview as? UILabel {
                    segmentLabel.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: segmentLabel.frame.size.width, height: segmentLabel.frame.size.height * 1.6)
                    if (multilinesMode == true)
                    {
                        segmentLabel.numberOfLines = 0
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        segmentLabel.numberOfLines = 1
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```